# What is the difference between s"foo $bar" and "foo %s".format(bar) in scala

Tags: scala, string-formatting

I am new to scala. I used to write formatted string in Scala in this way -> `"foo %s".format(bar)`. But recently I have found code that writes formatted string in this way -> `s"foo $bar"`. I was just wondering is there a major difference between the two?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`"foo %s".format(bar)`: Java `String.format` lays under the hood of this approach.

`s"foo $bar"`: It's scala's feature called `String interpolation` which allows create string literal in consise way. But compiler need some extra work to process such strings.